# Data is unavaliable before render in react native

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to pull data from the permanent storage on the beginning of my app, and then use this data to run a login function, but the data isn't avaliable when i try to run the function.
Example:

```
import store from 'react-native-simple-store'

class ExampleScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    }

  componentWillMount(){
    try {
      store.get('User').then((User) => this.setState({username: User}));
      store.get('Pass').then((Pass) => this.setState({password: Pass}));
    } catch(error){
      alert(error)
    };
    this.onSubmitPress;
  }

  onSubmitPress = async () => {
    alert(this.state.username);
    alert(this.state.password);
  }
}
```

The function returns the empty state set on the beginning ("").

How can i run a function with the data i get before the render?

Edit1: I need the data before the render to run the login function before i render the login screen.
I tried run on ComponentDidMount() but the data isn't avaliable until the render process starts (I can render this.state.username as a text on the render)

Comment: Why you need the data before the component get mounted? (in `Willmount`) Can you use it from `DidMount`? I mean, have you tested if it's load there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everyone has shared, you probably want to call your function after componentWillMount (call during componentDidMount). Unsure why would you need your data for rendering but I assume you need to render the UI based on your permanent storage.

According to your edit, "*I tried run on ComponentDidMount() but the data isn't avaliable until the render process starts*". The statement is incorrect, because the lifecycle is as below:

- componentWillMount > render > componentDidMount.

Meaning that, UI has rendered. Then your function will be fired at componentDidMount.

If you do not see your data in componentDidMount, kindly debug to verify if the data do exist in your permanent storage?

Side note: you should consider stop using [ComponentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

> That name will continue to work until version 17.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assure you can get the data before rendering. You can only get data in the previous screen or show a ActivityIndicator in the current screen to wait.